# jquery for how to find the next visible list tag

Tags: jquery

can any one help to find the next visible list tag from my down arrow key event?

HTML:

```
                        <ul class="langCountryListLeftPanel" data-bind="foreach: myLangListViewModel.CommonList">
                            <li style="display: none;">
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">⬛</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">Pashto</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">⬛</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">Dari</a>
                            </li>

                            <li style="display: none;">
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">Albanian</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">⬛</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">Dutch</a>
                            </li>

                            <li style="display: none;">
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">French</a>
                            </li>

                            <li style="display: none;">
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">German</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">English</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">⬛</span>
                                <a tabindex="20" class="columnLeft" data-bind="html:$data,  click: myLangListViewModel.showCountryList">Danish</a>
                            </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
    $('.langCountryListLeftPanel li a').keydown(function (e) {
                    // For keyboard shortcuts for "Down arrow" pressing 
                    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                        alert($(this).closest("li").next("li").is(':visible').text());
                        $(this).closest("li").next("li").find("a").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
   });
```

That is from the above html construct, when the focus is in any of list tag, from that if i press down arrow it need to focus only the next visible list tag, not the hidden one, how to find the next visible list tag or list tag anchor or text using jquery? any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As next() with :visible selector has some bug so Try this one:

   $(this).parent("li").nextAll("li:visible").first().text()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.nextAll("li:visible").eq(0)` and `.prevAll("li:visible").eq(0)` to get the next/previous visible li tag

```
 $('.langCountryListLeftPanel li a').keydown(function(e) {
     // For keyboard shortcuts for "Down arrow" pressing 
     if (e.keyCode == 40) {
         $(this).closest("li").nextAll("li:visible").eq(0).find("a").focus();
         return false;
     }
     // For keyboard shortcuts of "Up arrow" pressing 
     if (e.keyCode == 38) {
         $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li:visible").eq(0).find("a").focus();
         // if its first child focus goes to parent search input
         if ($(this).closest("li").is(':first-child')) {
             $(this).closest(".langCountrySearchContainer").find(".filterLangCountry").focus();
             return false;
         }
     }
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a0pw3119/75/)

Comment: Anoop: thanks its works fine, I also updated :first instead .eq(0), (i.e)  $(this).closest("li").nextAll("li:visible:first").find("a").focus(); and $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li:visible:first").find("a").focus();

Comment: Anoop: sorry, may i know where we have the green tick mark on my profile ?

Comment: Worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

try 
* `$('li').find(':not([style="display: none;"])');`