# I am using li tags with inner style display:none and without out display when i click next button select <li> without style none

Tags: jquery, css

Select next list tag without style display none.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#basic">Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item catagory-tab" data-tab_id="1" style="display: none;">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item catagory-tab" data-tab_id="3">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#category-tab-2">category tab-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item catagory-tab" data-tab_id="4">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#category-tab-3">category tab-3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item catagory-tab" data-tab_id="5" style="display: none;">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#cat-tab-3">cat tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery I used to get next li

```
$('.nav-pills > .nav-item > .active').parent().next('li'). find('a').trigger('click');
```

But i want to avoid li with display none

Comment: You can use :visible for visible elements and :hidden to find out hidden elements. So .next('li:visible')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery for how to find the next visible list tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402082/jquery-for-how-to-find-the-next-visible-list-tag)